# How to specify cursor pagination using timestamp in Prisma?

Tags: database, pagination, prisma

I want to use createdAt as cursor, but prisma's type only allow id field:

```
post.findMany({
      take: 10,
      orderBy: { createdAt: 'desc' },
      cursor: { id }, // Prisma only provide id here
    });
```

And cursor is refering to the type "postWhereUniqueInput", it only provide `id` in it:

```
  export type postWhereUniqueInput = {
    id?: number
  }
```

Here's the data model:

```
model post {
  id             Int            @id() @default(autoincrement())
  createdAt      DateTime       @default(now()) @db.Timestamp(6)
  updatedAt      DateTime       @default(now()) @db.Timestamp(6)
  title          String         @db.VarChar
  content        String?        @db.VarChar
  userId         Int  
  viewCount      Int            @default(0)  
  votePoints     Int            @default(0)
  likePoints     Int            @default(0)
  confusedPoints Int            @default(0)
  laughPoints    Int            @default(0)
  user           user           @relation(fields: [userId], references: [id], onDelete: Cascade, onUpdate: NoAction)
  interactions   interactions[]
  comments       comments[]
}
```

How can I use the timestamp as cursor? Thank you so much for the reply!

Comment: The docs say the field must be a unique, sequential column, I guess that's the problem, but I found a github discussion, seems interesting: https://github.com/prisma/prisma/discussions/4888

Comment: Did you manage to solve this in the end? I'm facing the same issue

Comment: @Luke I've take a look at the original project, think I solved by adding `@unique()` attribute. I posted the answer below.

Comment: Note that this will not work as you expect as the precision of the `Date` class in javascript is limited to milliseconds and `@db.Timestamp(6)` is microsecond precision. Did you figure this out?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Solution

By adding `@unique()` attribute:

```
model post {
  id             Int            @id() @default(autoincrement())
  createdAt      DateTime       @unique() @default(now())
  updatedAt      DateTime       @unique() @updatedAt
  ...
}
```

Then I can use cursor `createdAt`:

```
prismaService.post.findMany({
      cursor: cursor ? { createdAt: cursor } : undefined,
      ...
    });
```